# If $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, then $f$ is also differentiable in the direction $v$ at $x_{0}$, and $D_{v}f(x_{0}) = f'(x_{0})v$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

Let $E$ be a subset of $\textbf{R}^{n}$, $f:E\to\textbf{R}^{m}$ be a function, $x_{0}$ be an interior point of $E$, and let $v$ be a vector in $\textbf{R}^{n}$. If $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, then $f$ is also differentiable in the direction $v$ at $x_{0}$, and 
\begin{align*}
D_{v}f(x_{0}) = f'(x_{0})v
\end{align*}

**My solution**

According to the definition of differentiability, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_{0}}\frac{\|f(x) - (f(x_{0}) + f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0}))\|}{\|x-x_{0}\|} = 0
\end{align*}

If we make the substitution $x = x_{0} + tv$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\|v\|}\left\|\frac{f(x_{0} + tv) - f(x_{0})}{t} - f'(x_{0})v{}\right\|= 0
\end{align*}
which implies that $D_{v}f(x_{0}) = f'(x_{0})v$, and we are done.

Could someone please check the wording of my proof. Is it correct? Is there any theoretical flaw?

Comment: Based on the way you structured the argument, strictly speaking you would have to distinguish the case $v=0$ from the case $v \neq 0$. Also, depending on how careful you're required to be, you'd need to give a more explicit justification of why the second equation follows from the first. Lastly, the definition of directional derivative requires $t \to 0$, not just $t \to 0^+$. (I would highly recommed you take a look at Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus text, page 146-148, especially Theorem 7.2).